# Beanstalk deployment ignores my nginx configuration files in .ebextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I host my Java webapp on a single-instance Elastic Beanstalk environment and I added several ebextension files which successfully create config files for me upon each deployment. I can't however find a way of getting Beanstalk to add new configs within the `/etc/nginx` or `/etc/nginx/conf.d` directories.

I followed the steps described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-java.html

My deployment package structure looks like this:

```
$ zip -r deploy.zip api-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar .ebextensions
  adding: api-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar (deflated 11%)
  adding: .ebextensions/ (stored 0%)
  adding: .ebextensions/ssl-certificates.config (deflated 37%)
  adding: .ebextensions/https-instance-securitygroup.config (deflated 38%)
  adding: .ebextensions/nginx/ (stored 0%)
  adding: .ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/ (stored 0%)
  adding: .ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/https.conf (deflated 61%)
```

My files are nearly 1-to-1 copy of samples in the guide above.

During deployment both my `*.config` files execute successfully, but the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/https.conf` is missing. I tried to workaround the issue by removing the `.ebextensions/nginx` directory and replacing it with another `.config` file that creates `/etc/nginx/conf.d/https.conf` from scratch, but this didn't help and the file was still missing.

I ssh-ed onto my EC2 instance and here's what I found in `/var/log/eb-engine.log`:

```
2020/05/03 19:42:37.754375 [INFO] Executing instruction: configure proxy Nginx
2020/05/03 19:42:37.754393 [WARN] skipping nginx folder under .ebextensions
2020/05/03 19:42:37.754670 [INFO] No plugin in cfn metadata.
```

I feel like I might have missed something very obvious here, but surprisingly I couldn't find any solution to my problem. Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: I also use post-deploy hook to setup a similar proxy_pass. Recently I found that Beanstalk removes custom ngixn config files if webapp is restarted by changing environment variables in Elastic Beanstalk > Environments > "env-name" > Configuration > Software. Do you guy have the same problem where ngixn config gets lost?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have just solved the same problem.

you can easily solve the problem by configuring the following directory structure.

```
~/my-app/
|-- readme.md
|-- .ebextensions/
|   |-- options.config       # Option settings
|   -- cloudwatch.config     # Other .ebextensions sections, for example 
-- .platform/
    -- nginx/                # Proxy configuration
        |-- nginx.conf
        -- conf.d/
            -- custom.conf
            -- elasticbeanstalk
               |-- server.conf
```

for more information, see this [url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html)

my /var/log/eb-engine.log showed the message line below.

```
Running command /bin/sh -c cp -rp /var/app/staging/.platform/nginx/. /var/proxy/staging/nginx
```

Comment: This looks much more elegant that my workaround, thank you!
I'll give it a run later this evening and if it'll works I'll accept it.

Comment: Frustratingly, it looks like AWS's documentation is lagging behind its actual platform.

Comment: THIS WAS THE ANSWER - I went through at least 100 posts and spent 72 hours working on this simple problem.

Comment: @yuya.tajima I'm trying to extend nginx config as you did but it is not working, at least for me. As docs stated .platform/nginx/ should be copied into /etc/nginx/conf.d (where nginx config is) but it didn't. Could you explain if you did any other change? Is it still working? I'm thinking to copy the files using Buildfile

Comment: To reiterate @andrewoodleyjr , this should be the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me too! Just to clarify as the formatting of the answer was a tiny bit difficult to read, the .platform directory should go on the same level as the .ebextensions directory

Comment: does it work for Node.js running on 64bit Amazon Linux?

Comment: This has stopped working for me. AWS seems to have broken this functionality.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same problem.
The solution is to put the https.conf file in the path `.platform/nginx/conf.d/https.conf` and zip it into the deployment package.

See "Reverse proxy configuration" in this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

Answer (score 4):

I feel like I'm the only person on the internet with this problem. ;-)

After digging into the logs a little bit more I realised that Beanstalk simply overwrites my nginx configuration at the very end of a deployment process. This meant that all the files my `.ebextensions` created were lost.

I haven't managed to find a "proper" solution, but I worked it around with a postdeploy hook. My nginx config file is now generated in `/home/ec2-user`, rather than `/etc/nginx`, like this:

```
files:
  /home/ec2-user/https.conf:
    content: |
      server {
        listen       443;
        server_name  localhost;

        ssl                  on;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;

        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

        location / {
          proxy_pass  http://localhost:5000;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   https;
        }
      }
```

And then in `.platform/hooks/postdeploy/99_hack_nginx.sh` (make sure this directory is included in your deployment package - in the same way as `.ebextensions`):

```
cp /home/ec2-user/https.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

Make sure it has a proper mode:

```
chmod +x .platform/hooks/postdeploy/99_hack_nginx.sh
```

Deploy, and enjoy your HTTPS traffic.

Comment: I have exactly the same probem...It makes two of us. Did you manage to find a more elegant solution?

Comment: The proper solution is what @yuya.tajima and Sivelli wrote. 
 Put https.conf in .platform/nginx/conf.d/   Then you can delete the postdeploy hook and the code in ebextensions.