# ASP.NET Core 3.1 on AWS Elastic Beanstalk Linux managed instances with load balancer - HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have setup a AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment.

So far, everything is fine, and the SSL works at the Load Balancer and forwards requests to the internal port 80 on the Linux instances behind the scenes.

However, when trying to use the out of the box "Login with Google" / "Login with Office 365" I'm now getting URL referrer errors as the instance is passing `http://www.domainname.com` as itself isn't running SSL.

I've followed the guide here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-dotnet-linux.html

I have the SSL certs and key in place, and the conf file setup, however the instances still do not appear to be accepting SSL connections.

I either need to override the `_signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties` method to always use HTTPS, or get the instances running HTTPS.

I've tried different proxy ports, 80, 5000 and 5001 but I'd assume Kestrel doesn't need a certificate as that's what Nginx is doing and internally proxying the traffic to the HTTP kestrel server?

I also have an instance in the AWS Network I can RDP to and run a local network request, i.e. browse to http://10.x.x.x of one of the instances, this works but again not via HTTPS.

Comment: This should not be a problem since the SSL terminates on the LB, and Elastic Beanstalk environment should be getting requests with HTTP only. Did you check logs from Elastic Beanstalk env?

Comment: So the request for the OAuth is `http://` as the application is `http://` - it's technically fine, I just need to get the OAuth requests in `https://` rather than the internal scheme

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question, but if you want to enforce SSL/HTTPS, then you can add redirects from http to https. If you are using ALB: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/

Comment: OK, what's the instance ports to forward the ALB to? As 443 doesn't work at the instance level, only port 80. So the End to End encryption isn't there either

Comment: However, it may be this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61580965/beanstalk-deployment-ignores-my-nginx-configuration-files-in-ebextensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there's a few things at play here.

First, running ASP.NET Core web applications behind a proxy or load balancer you need to add the appropriate headers:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-5.0

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHeaders =
                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        });
```

And in `ConfigureServices` add:

`app.UseForwardedHeaders();`

This allows the application to use the proxy addresses.

In my instance, I wanted TLS between the Load Balancer and the instances as well, which is a different thing as well.

So the `.ebextensions` folder needs the config to add the certificate to the instance as per the guide here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-dotnet-linux.html
You need to add the public and private keys.

The additional Nginx config needs to go into the `.platform` folder, which isn't in the documentation but is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html
And here:
[Beanstalk deployment ignores my nginx configuration files in .ebextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61580965/beanstalk-deployment-ignores-my-nginx-configuration-files-in-ebextensions)

If it's not then a SSL listener will need be applied.

Now I have TLS pass through from the Load Balancer and more importantly, the OAuth config works as the application knows it's `https://` and passes the correct referrer URL.

Also, the Kestrel runs on the default port of 5000. You can add a listener for both http (port 80) and https (443) to both go to this port.